# Диаграммы .Net + ActiveX

Tags: c#, winforms, activex

Имеется `WinForms` проект, использующий одновременно, т.е. на одной форме, как `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`, так и `ActiveX`, написанную на древнем `Borland C++ Builder 6`.

Как оказалось, вместе они дружат не очень хорошо, а именно наблюдаются странные эффекты:

- На одной машине приложение работает, но при первом открытии формы вместо графика рисуется белый фон. При повторном открытии уже всё хорошо. Так же проблему можно решить однократным вызовом `Refresh` по таймеру после загрузки формы (вместо переоткрытия).
- В другой ситуации вылезает `System.ArithmeticException`, по которому была найдена [статейка](https://toster.ru/q/213686) о возможной причине такого поведения:

> Определённые функции некоторых версий Delphi, c++ любят менять бит в FPU-регистре CW на такое значение, что бедный математический сопроцессор перестаёт переваривать double.NaN, начиная плеваться на него исключениями. А в WPF, как известно, у доброй половины свойств FrameworkElement-а значение по умолчанию выставлено именно в NaN. При малейших манипуляциях над этими свойствами приложение начинает падать.

Но если в случае `P/Invoke` более менее понятно, т.е. вызвал функцию, вернул регистры, всё ОК. То в случае параллельно работающей `ActiveX` как-то не ясно, в какой момент эти регистры надо править.

- В третьем случае, при попытки открытия такой формы в дизайнере Visual Studio IDE просто падает.
- Ну и в четвертой ситуации (ещё один комп), вылезает:

  > `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll`

  при попытке запуска голого приложения из одной формы с двумя упомянутыми компонентами на ней.

Исходники имеются (т.е. можно модифицировать), но, к сожалению, опубликовать их не могу.

Теряюсь в догадках, как можно разрешить проблему сосуществования этих компонентов на одной форме. Ваши идеи?

Comment: Чисто теоретически, может быть можно заагрегировать этот самый ActiveX своим объектом, и в функциях-обёртках сохранять/восстанавливать состояние FPU?

Comment: @VladD своим объектом - это как?

Comment: Ну, я имел в виду написать собственный COM-класс-обёртку, имплементировать тот же COM interface, а в имплементации все вызовы перенаправить экземпляру «настоящего» объекта.

Comment: @VladD обернуть COM от Borland в COM от Microsoft?

Comment: В COM от вас лично :)

Comment: @VladD просто обертку тоже придется на каком-то каркасе строить, например тот же C++Builder генерит автоматом много обвязочного кода к ActiveX. В котором, если я правильно понимаю, как раз можно было бы добавить обвес с сохранением/восстановлением регистров. В общем пока не очень ясна процедура реализации сей идеи. С COM, к сожалению, знаком достаточно поверхностно.

Comment: Ну, написать легче всего, наверное, на том же C++/MSVC. Я не очень спец по COM, но думаю, что информации на MSDN должно быть много. Как я понимаю, COM-объект должен выставить и реализовать интерфейс, а вы можете реализовать тот же интерфейс, таким образом ваш объект можно будет использовать вместо этого самого ActiveX-объекта. (По сути, ActiveX == COM.)